# C segfault with nested structure-pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault

I am pretty new to C and trying to understand it better, but I occured some strange behavior, which I do not fully understand:
I have this 2 structs:

```c
typedef struct edge
{
    int start_node;
    int end_node;
} edge;


typedef struct graph 
{
    int node_count;
    edge *edges;
} graph;
```

If I now initalize my graph (allocating the memory):

```c
    graph *g = malloc((sizeof(edge )* (edge_amount)) + sizeof(int));
```

If I now try to initalize my edges like:
(calling the function parse_graph(g->edges);)

```c
void parse_graph(edge *edges){
 for (int i = 0; i < edge_amount ; i++)
    {
      

        edge edge;
        edge.start_node = some int
        edge.end_node = some int
        edges[i] = edge;
    }
}
```

I am getting a segfault in the edges[i] = edge line.
But, when I initalize my graph (only the edges) like:

```c
 edge *g= malloc((sizeof(edge )* (edge_amount)) + sizeof(int));
```

And I call the function like parseInput(g), I do not get the segfault.
I am sure I have forgot something important, but I can not figure it out. What I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you're allocating more space for a `graph` than the size of the structure.

Second off, your allocation is not doing what you think.  Think about what address `g->edges` contains after your allocation.

There are also struct packing issues you're not accounting for.

Anyway, what you need to do is

```
g = malloc(sizeof(graph));
if ( !g ) {
    // error handling
}
g->num_edges = edge_amount;
g->edges = malloc(sizeof(edge)*edge_amount);
if ( !g->edges ) {
    // error handling
}
```